# Objective C - Push to a view controller not in tabBarController's tabs programmatically

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar controller which contains 3 view controllers, and in 1 of those view controllers, I have a button to present another view controller not in the tab bar controller. The functions in the button run, but the other view controller does not show up. To be more specific, the 3 view controllers in the tab bar is the ProfilePage, EditProfile page and AllUsersProfile page. And in my ProfilePage, I have a logout button to go back to the login screen, which is not part of the tabBar.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)scene:(UIScene *)scene willConnectToSession:(UISceneSession *)session options:(UISceneConnectionOptions *)connectionOptions {
    // last login
    NSString * username = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SessionKey"];
    Users* lastUser =[LocalStorageController loadCustomObjectWithKey:username];
    ProfilePage *lastUserProfile = [[ProfilePage alloc] initWithUser:lastUser];
    EditProfile *lastUserEdit = [[EditProfile alloc]initWithUser:lastUser];
    AllUsersProfile *lastUserViewAll = [[AllUsersProfile alloc]init];
    
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

        NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:lastUserProfile,lastUserEdit,lastUserViewAll,nil];

        [tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:NO];
        [tabBarController release];
        self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;

    lastUserEdit.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit Profile" image:nil selectedImage:nil];
    lastUserProfile.tabBarItem =[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Home" image:nil selectedImage:nil];
    lastUserViewAll.tabBarItem =[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"View Others" image:nil selectedImage:nil];
```

And here is the code for logout:

```
- (void) logOut{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: nil]; //this does not show the LoginScreen view controller
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the current code to present a new controller in TabBar controllers.

// You have three UIViewControllers

```
- (void)scene:(UIScene *)scene willConnectToSession:(UISceneSession *)session options:(UISceneConnectionOptions *)connectionOptions {

    ViewControllerTab1 * tabVC1 = [[ViewControllerTab1 alloc] init];
    ViewControllerTab2 * tabVC2 = [[ViewControllerTab2 alloc] init];
    ViewControllerTab3 * tabVC3 = [[ViewControllerTab3 alloc] init];

    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    NSArray * viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:tabVC1,  tabVC2,  tabVC3, nil];
    [tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:NO];
    
    self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;

    tabVC1.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit Profile" image:nil selectedImage:nil];
    tabVC2.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Home" image:nil selectedImage:nil];
    tabVC3.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"View Others" image:nil selectedImage:nil];
}
```

In ViewControllerTab1, present NewViewController which you want as per your requirement

```
-(void)presentAnotherVC{
    NewViewController * vc = [[NewViewController alloc]init];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

In NewViewController, dismiss NewViewController to go back to selected TabBar controller

```
-(void)dsmissThisVC{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```